# Text overflow in Bootstrap responsive table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap responsive table. The problem I am facing here is the text in the table column is overflowing. As per my knowledge the table adjusts the column width automatically if it is responsive. But the problem here is I have a input field inside td and I have a placeholder for that input field. The placeholder is getting overflowed. How to fix this issue for this requirement. **Placeholder : Drag and Drop here**

**Note: This problem happens in mobile device only.**

```
<div class="table-responsive border">
<table class="table" id="dataTable" width="100%" style="overflow-x:auto">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Document Type</th>
         <th class="text-center">Upload</th>
         <th>Open</th>
         <th>Resolved</th>
         <th>Not Required</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="missingBody">
      <tr>
         <tdFront and Back - Passport/Driver’s License/Photo Car</td>
         <td>
            <div class="file-field">
               <div class="file-path-wrapper""><input type="file" name="file1" missval="dcn_56"  multiple=""><input style="vertical-align:top;padding-bottom:8px;" class="file-path validate" type="text" id="dcn_56" doctype="56" multiple="" placeholder="Drag and Drop files here"></div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td><input type="radio" id="open56" missinginfoid="56" checked="" value="71" name="Missing0" class="custom-control-input"><label class="custom-control-label" for="open56"></label></td>
         <td><input type="radio" id="resolve56" missinginfoid="56" value="72" name="Missing0" class="custom-control-input"><label class="custom-control-label" for="resolve56"></label></td>
         <td><input type="radio" id="close56" missinginfoid="56" value="73" name="Missing0" class="custom-control-input"><label class="custom-control-label" for="close56"></label></td>
      </tr>
     
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Ouput:** https://ibb.co/TrCSrk4

The output should look like drag and drop here in same line